# How to cast an object to internal class

Tags: c#, reflection

I am viewing source code of an internal .Net class and want to modify a function using reflection. (By rewriting every single line of the original function into a new function using reflection and add my modification into it)

```
object responseObject = request.ConnectionAsyncResult.InternalWaitForCompletion();
ConnectStream writeStream = responseObject as ConnectStream;
if (writeStream == null) ...
```

How should I write the second line of the code ?

**The code is checking if an object is specific class but I have no idea how to do this if the class is an internal class. How to cast an object into an internal class?**

**ConnectStream is an internal class**

Comment: *"modify a function"* - how do you intend to do that? I don't think that C# has metaprogramming capabilities. Am I wrong there?

Comment: I rewrite every single line of the original function using reflection and add my modification into it

Comment: How do you rewrite the methods?

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain well. I rewite every single lines of the original method by reflection into a new method

Comment: @IsoletChan Do you mean reflection, or do you mean disassembly (i.e. extract equivalent source-code using a disassembly tool such as ILSpy or Reflector)?

Comment: What is this code actually trying to do? Im pretty sure you're going to struggle to create an instance of an internal class but the functionality might be possible in other ways

Comment: Do you use Reflection.Emit?

Comment: @thehennyy No, I literally rewite every single line of the code since I need to add modification midway

Comment: @Sayse I am trying to separate a bundled method into a few methods so I can have separated methods to call.

Comment: Thats what your trying to do, but what is the *code* supposed to do?

Comment: @Sayse The code is checking if an object is specific class but I have no idea how to do this if the class is an internal class

Comment: You're still talking about your immediate problem, but not what you're actually trying to do. Why did you get into modifying internal classes in the first place? It's very likely that the only reason you have to solve this particular sub-problem is because you're choosing a particularly convoluted approach to solving your *real* problem.

Comment: @Luaan  I am trying to separate a bundled method into a few methods so I can have separated methods to call.

Comment: You've already said that, but that's still way too low level - it's still just one of those tiny details to implement some solution. But what are you trying to find a solution for? Why do you need to meddle with internal, infrastructural code? Why can't you use some documented extension point or something? What is so special about your problem that it requires rewriting the methods of .NET core classes? Is it really worth the cost of fixing all the problems that inevitably crop up when some .NET update pops up?

Comment: If you just want to check if the object has a type which matches a name, you can do `bool isTypeCalledConnectStream = responseObject != null && responseObject.GetType().Name == "ConnectStream"; if (!isTypeCalledConnectStream) { ... }` but I do not understand your needs.

Comment: @Luaan Yes, I come to this last worst performance-wise solution after many attempts. I am using fasterflect for the reflection code and find that the performance is quite satisfying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you don't. You'll just have to use reflection for every single step - the compiler sure isn't going to help you :)

"Rewriting every single line" is a bad idea anyway - it's a bit trickier to get code that actually works. Instead, you'll probably just want to make your helper method call the original method, as well as do whatever you need done.

When using reflection, you don't need to know the types at compile-time, and you don't need to abide to all C#'s rules. A code that's roughly equivalent to your original could look something like this:

```
if (responseObject != null && responseObject.GetType().Name == "ConnectStream")
```

Depending on your actual needs, there are better ways to make that check as well - for example, you could take the `System.Net` assembly and find the `ConnectStream` type with the proper namespace and everything, and compare the two `Type` instances directly. But in code like this, it isn't really necessary.

Comment: I need to add modification amid the method so I can not call the original method. I know I need to use reflection for every single step and I am asking how should I write the second line of the code. Sorry if my question is unclear

Comment: @IsoletChan That's what I'm telling you - you don't. You'll have to use the Reflection APIs to call whatever you need to call, and do whatever type checks necessary. Literally, `responseObject.GetType().GetMethod(...).Invoke(...);`. It's *very* tedious, but that's the price you pay for breaking invariants :)

Comment: Yes, I am using reflection api and writing these tedious code. How would you write the second line of the code?

Comment: @IsoletChan You don't *cast* anything - reflection is ultimately untyped (that is, all those methods like `Invoke` take `object`). So if you want to call a method on `object` that might be `ConnectStream`, you just call `Invoke(writeStream)`. If you want to check if `object` *is* a `ConnectStream`, you'll do something like `if (writeStream.GetType().Name == "ConnectStream")` (tweak as needed). Neither reflection nor IL is C# - the rules are different. You're basically forcing yourself to do a complicated thing because that's how C# does it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explantation. I am stuck at how to cast it to an internal class. The answer is like you said, no casting is needed, checking its type is enough. I am curious that why the original code do not simply check the type but cast it using as operator?

Comment: Could you add the checking type part to your answer so I could mark it as the answer?